# iOS - Drag finger over grid of views

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a superview with a grid of subviews.  When I drag over/out of the subviews I want to alter its properties (similar to `UIKeyboard` on iPhone).  The subviews are `UIButton` subclasses.

I'm thinking I need to do some kind of touch forwarding from the superview but I'm not clear how it works.  What is the right combination of these methods?

[– touchesBegan:withEvent:

– touchesMoved:withEvent:

– touchesEnded:withEvent:

– touchesCancelled:withEvent:](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[hitTest:withEvent:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

on your superview.

A possible approach is identifying in `touchesMoved` which subview is currently "under the touch" (i.e., which the touch location is in) and change its status accordingly.

```
 -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
     UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
     CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
     if(CGRectContainsPoint(subview1.frame, location)) {
         ...
     }
 }
```

`touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` would not play a major role in this; they would only be useful to start and end the "tracking" you do in `touchesMoved`.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches]; 
    <save initial touch if you need it>
}


-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    <do whatever>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Would hitTest be suitable for getting the subview from touchesMoved?

Comment: Sure you can; though, hitTest transverse all the subviews hierarchy. If you have any kind of regular layout of your subviews you might be better off by some kind of math that gives you the affected subview...